# How to start a PowerShell script from where it stopped? (For scanning repos by cloning)

Tags: powershell, github, session, powershell-2.0, git-clone

I have written a PowerShell script to scan the repos by cloning from GitHub and it's running as expected. Now I have got a new request to add a feature.ie., when a script fails due to some reasons like ctrl+c (or) switch off the machine unexpectedly, and when we run again, it should start from where it got left before, so it shouldn't perform the clone operation which was already done in previous run and it should continue from the last run only.

Is this possible in powershell or not?

Comment: Perhaps have the script create a log file and write the steps it has already done each time. When restarted, it could check if there are still steps that nee doing and carry on from there.

Comment: Theo, Can you plz share some code snippet on this logic